# Please update the FAQ to reflect soft questions are OK

Tags: support

There was a fair amount of contention about [Onepage checkout, or not Onepage checkout](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/89/onepage-checkout-or-not-onepage-checkout), and it seems to be considered a valid question. The contention may largely have been over confusion about the FAQ, which still states *Chatty, open-ended questions diminish the usefulness of our site and push other questions off the front page.*

Since the above question is an open-ended question, and is valid, the FAQ must be out of date. To avoid future confusion, can it please be updated?

Answer (score 1):

Read that quote [in context](https://magento.stackexchange.com/faq#dontask):

> You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face. Chatty, open-ended questions diminish the usefulness of our site and push other questions off the front page.

Is this question practical? Answerable? IMHO, it's borderline - the asker is soliciting opinions, hoping to extract from them a rationale for such replacement. A better question might ask what deficiencies third-party checkouts correct.

The biggest problem with that question is there's no clear problem statement. The asker holds a dim view of 3rd-party solutions, considers them unnecessary, and is looking for confirmation of this. Note that the accepted answer closely mirrors the asker's opinion stated in the question itself!

> - there is no actual problem to be solved: “I’m curious if other people feel like I do.”

I strongly suspect this question will need some serious clean-up in the near future, and it has already attracted a couple of non-answers.

Rather than changing the FAQ, I suggest you look for ways to change the question to:

- clearly state an actual problem
- provide context, identify constraints
- request answers that go into detail, [explain the problems and back up these explanations with facts and personal experiences](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/).

Right now, there are a few decent answers amidst a lot of opinions and hand-wavy "this is what I do" responses. If you want this to be useful a month, six months, or a year down the road, planning for that now is essential.

Comment: If this were stackoverflow or some other vetted, long-lived SE site I would have no problem changing the question. I opted to ask this meta question because it's not clear (read: I'm not sure) what is a desired question here, and thus it would be inappropriate for me to do the editing. You seem to make the case that the question is of poor quality, if not outright wrong, but the question of whether or not it's a good fit for m.se is ultimately black-and-white: While the question is open, it sets precedent.