# Meta-meta: No FAQ tag?

Tags: discussion

When I posted [this meta question](https://magento.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39/please-update-the-faq-to-reflect-soft-questions-are-ok) I was surprised I couldn't add the tag `faq` to it. (Evidently it's moderator-only.) What is the appropriate tag to use to indicate a meta question about the FAQ?

Answer (score 1):

Questions about the [`/faq` page](https://magento.stackexchange.com/faq) are tagged [site-faq](/questions/tagged/site-faq), following [the main meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/site-faq/info).

Questions tagged [faq](/questions/tagged/faq) on meta are community-maintained complements to the primary FAQ. Only moderators can set that tag. If you want to propose a meta question for the [faq](/questions/tagged/faq), tag it [faq-proposed](/questions/tagged/faq-proposed) and prod the moderators after a while (again following [the main meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/faq-proposed/info)).

Comment: Unfortunately `site-faq` seems to be a *new* tag for this meta-site, and I don't have enough reputation to create it.

Comment: Unfortunately I do not have an answer for that question, but I did go and add the `site-faq` tag to it for you.